# Javascript/JSP: How to pass JSP variables value on one page to javascript variables on next page?

Tags: javascript, jsp

Currently I am trying to send JSP value to javascript. Is it possible? My cases is as follows:

On Page abc.jsp, user enters data in form. Which is send on the next page xyz.jsp. I want to use this data in xyz.jsp pages javascript. Is it possible? Is yes how to do this?

also would like to know, if I auto refresh this page(or part of page) ie xyz.jsp then is it possible without javascript failing or crashing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let JSP print it as if it is a JS variable. Assuming that you've variable `${foo}` in JSP:

```
<script>var foo = '${foo}';</script>
```

This will end up in webbrowser as

```
<script>var foo = 'somevalue';</script>
```

Keep in mind: JSP runs at webserver and produces HTML. JS is part of HTML and runs at webbrowser.

#### See also:

- [How to communicate between JavaScript and Java/JSP/JSF?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html)